# Spring Security returning the same token each time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

We're using spring security (Authorisation and Resource server ) in our project.

1. client sends a token request (/oauth/token) with the oauth2 parameters.
2. spring security app creates a token for the user and respond to the client with the access_token, refresh_token, custom user object (name, organisation, email etc) and authorities (Roles).
3. Client adds additional roles (say ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_USER).
4. spring application will store the above roles for the given user.
5. Next time when client sends a token request, spring security returns the previously created token (not expired yet) along with the user and authority information. This authority information is not having the latest roles (added in step4).

Here spring security always using the existing token (as it is not expired) and returning the valid token. Is this the expected behaviour even though the user object is being modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to revoke the access token when the users roles change if you want the next request to get a new access token with the new roles and not return an existing token with existing roles if it's still valid.

At the point where you update the users roles you'd likely want to revoke the token.
I haven't personally tested this but I found a guide for it here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-revoke-tokens so your milage may vary.

I want to add that this does not sound like the normal OAuth2 process and you may be breaking a few conventions here which might bite you later. That said, you don't have to follow a standard if you're confident in your proposed solution.

Edit: To clarify the users roles and access is normally part of a resource and not part of the token exchange. For example you have a normal OAuth2 request which generates a token which you can exchange for an access token, as you've laid out in steps 1 and 2. Then you'd normally take that access token and request user access information from a resource such as "userinfo" service or something similar.

Your security service can also be a resource server but the two steps should be seen as different. Then when you want to modify the users roles you do this again through a resource. This means the next time you invoke the resource it'll have the up to date information without needing to authenticate the user again.